# Pre or post process some node's options (nodes in node and main node labels)

Tags: macros, nodes

For setting sub nodes in node I use the following code (provided by Mark Wibrow):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
add text/.style args={#1:#2}{append after command =
                {node[rounded corners, fill=blue!10] at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) [anchor=#1] {#2}}
                            },
    box/.style={rectangle, draw, densely dotted, thick,
                text width=3.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm,
                align=center,
                append after command = {\pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},#1
                },
                    ]
\node[box,
      label=above:label,   % <--- work fine
      add text=north:lorum,
      add text=south west:ipsum,
      add text=east:dolor,
%      label=above:test   % <--- gives error "no shape named is known"
    ]   {main\\ content};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

This code work fine if label of main node is before `add text` in node's options. For some (important) reason, I like to have labels after `add text` macro. Is there a way to tell in node definition, that the `add text` had to be performed last between nodes options, so the order of `label` and `add text` in node's options is not important any more?

Comment: Do you have a link for Mark Wibrow's code?

Comment: He send it to `pgf-user mailing list`, 2013-03-24 07:20. Code in my example is almost identical to his post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, though I'm not at all clear why you need to use `label` so I'm not at all sure this is an option.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
% code for sub-nodes (in the non-tikzmark sense) from Mark Wibrow: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/yunrzHUfSUk/y3x-QWP7sJ0J
\makeatletter
\def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    add text/.style args={#1:#2}{append after command =
      {node [rounded corners, fill=blue!10] at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) [anchor=#1] {#2}}
    },
    my label/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{append after command =
      {node [every label] at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) [anchor=#2] {#3}}
    },
    box/.style={rectangle, draw, densely dotted, thick,
      text width=3.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm,
      align=center,
      append after command = {\pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},
      #1,
    },
  ]
  \node [box={draw=red},
  label=above:label,   % <--- work fine
  add text=north:lorum,
  add text=south west:ipsum,
  add text=east:dolor,
  my label=south:north:test   % <--- also works
  ]   {main\\ content};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: my label option]

Comment: Dear @cfr, +1! This works! I only need to finish some tests in final applications and integrated with my other styles definitions  in common `tikzset` for my temporary project .

Comment: OK. Good. I tried to make it work with `label` but the code is beyond me. You need somehow to reset the 'last node name' to the name of the node rather than the name of the `add text` node. If you take your code and you name the `add text` node e.g. `(b)` then you'll see it compiles without error and you can see the problem. (The label is in the wrong place, but you can understand what is happening better.) Apparently, the `add text` nodes don't get implicit names, so it only works with an explicit one.

Comment: I just finished all my test. Your solution works in all my uses, however it require some effort (after time not using your solution) to figured out, why there are two anchors for `my label`. So I, decided to temporary use your solution, but meanwhile I will reinspect style and system of my  illustration design and check again if I really need so sophisticated solution(s). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It should be possible to do without it by either emulating the effect of `label` but using the correct node or changing the relevant node before actually calling `label`. But I am not sure how to do either of these. Or tell TikZ that the `after text` nodes are labels ....

Comment: This last I test the first. Unsuccessfully. Something similar to `after text`  in TikZ manual I found only examples, which work on paths.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is `\pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name\tikz@node@is@a@labelfalse}` in the definition of `\tikz@@parse@label@nonactive[#1]#2:#3:\pgf@nil` which is setting the node TikZ tries to use i.e. the most recent node created using `add text`. I'm not sure which part of the manual you're referring to. I'm looking at `tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`.

Comment: I'm not digging in TikZ code, just read a manual, mostly 3. chapter (TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogram).